# jQuery cluetip activation

Tags: jquery, cluetip

How make activate [cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) on event ready or onload?

> The clueTip plugin allows you to easily show a fancy tooltip when the
>   user's mouse hovers over (or, optionally, clicks on) any element you
>   designate in your script. If the element includes a title attribute,
>   its text becomes the heading of the clueTip.

Comment: You mean to show the tooltip when page loads ? All the tooltips or a specific one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the tooltip is shown while hovering the element you applied it on (see the [default options](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#options))
This can be changed to the `click` event, I'll demonstrate both.

The idea is to programmatically trigger the event `mouseenter` (there no real *hover* event but a combination of *mouseenter* and *mouseleave*).

You can do this by using `.trigger('mouseenter')` or `.mouseenter()`

Let's say you want to open the tooltip on a link:

```
<a href="#" id="mylink" title="This is the title|The first the content.|In this case, the delimiter is a pipe">My link</a>
```

You'll have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $link = $('#mylink');

    // first initialize the plugin
    $link.cluetip({
        splitTitle: '|'
    });

    // trigger the event
    $link.mouseenter(); // or $link.click(); 

});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/afUXc/) for you to play with.

Documentation of [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)